# Red Badge in the lightning tab

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, css, html

Hi I am working in the lwc lightning tab set in which i need to put a number in the lightning tab label
and enclosed that number on red error badge ... but not sure how to use this one.
Class for the number : slds-theme_error slds-badge

image shown as below:
[image]

kindly help me out to show the '3' shown in the above image in red badge with the help of class
slds-theme_error slds-badge
something like this : [image]

Below is the code :

```
 <lightning-tab label='communication 3' value='communication'></lightning-tab>
```

Kindly help me out for this

Comment: I am providing you two links, see if these are useful or not: 1. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/badges/  2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_setTabHighlighted.htm

Comment: I have a similar requirement, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The standard lightning tab(lwc) does not support this. But you can build the custom one using the lightning base component recipes.

[lightning tab base component code](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/tab)

[lightning tabset base component code](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/tabset)